# Linked Tables and SQL SELECT Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few linked tables in my custom forum: `categories`, `sub_categories` and `posts`

basically, I have people able to add up to three categories and five sub-categories when they make a new post.

I also enable people to 'listen' to certain categories and sub-categories and have them in an easy to access bar at the side of the page.

My tables are set up thus (only showing relavent fields for ease):

**posts:**

```
id              INT
category_id     VARCHAR(12)
sub_category_id VARCHAR(35)
```

**categories:**

```
id      INT
name    VARCHAR(20)
```

**sub_categories:**

```
id      INT
name    VARCHAR(20)
```

in my `posts` table, I store the set categories and sub-categories by their ID in the following format:

```
category_id     [2][4][8]
sub_category_id [1][2][3][4][5]
```

thus enabling me to execute the following query in PHP and get the post based on category and sub-category:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id LIKE '%[{$id}]%' AND sub_category_id LIKE '%[{$id2}]%'
```

the problem I have is selecting the `sub_categories` for the access bar that people 'listen' to...

```
$sql = "SELECT title, id FROM categories";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$list = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $list[$row['title']] = array();
    $sql = "SELECT sub_categories.title FROM sub_categories, posts WHERE (category_id LIKE '%[{$row['id']}]%') AND (????) LIMIT 0,100";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $list[$row['title']][] = $result['title'];
    }
}
print_r($list);
```

Obviously you can see where I am stuck `(????)`, but before I explain what I am trying to do, I'll explain what the output I am looking for is.

when I print the `$list` array, I want it to print a multi-dimensional array featuring the categories as the first key, with their values being an array of sub-categories that have been tagged in the main category.

The problem I have is that in my `sub_category_id` field on the post table, remember the values are stored in the format `[1][2][3]` and I need to check the value against the subcategory field `id`.

I have tried the following:

```
"SELECT sub_categories.title FROM sub_categories, posts WHERE (category_id LIKE '%[{$row['id']}]%') AND (sub_category_id LIKE '%[sub_categories.id]%') LIMIT 0,100"
```

But it didn't work. I don't know whether there is an error in my query or whether it even SHOULD work, but I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to do it or where I am going wrong in my code!

**NB. I am trying to find which `sub_categories` appear in which `categories` based on people tagging them in a post together.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're facing problems because you're not aware about few concepts in database...

In your case, you want to create associations called "many-to-many".
It means that a category can be used in many post and a post can be represented by many category.

To translate that into a "SQL" world, you have to create an intermediate table.

this table will store both identifier of the two tables.

for exemple:

```
-------------------
|  categorisation |
-------------------
|    post_id      |  => is the link to posts
|   category_id   |  => is the link to categories
-------------------
```

When you create a new post, you create a new object in the table post. But you also create N  records in the table categorisation.

When you want to retrieve which categories applied to this post, you can do a query like that:

```
SELECT post.id, post.name 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN categorisation on (post.id = categorisation.post_id)
INNER JOIN category ON (categorisation.category_id = category.id)
```

I think you need to read some articles on the web about database before progressing in you project ;)

Comment: ... I can't believe it. I actually use this exact solution to store users favorite categories and subcategories... for some reason I completely forgot about it because I was concentrating on the problem, not the solution!

Comment: One more tip: you could have a single table for categories and subcategories, with columns `id`, `parent_id` (NULLABLE), and `name`. That way, you'd also enforce the relationship between every subcategory and its parent category.

Comment: Due to the nature of the forum I am building, subcategories can belong to multiple categories. It's for manga, anime and Japanese culture, including fan-fiction and fan-art, so basically, someone might like a manga (ie. Naruto) and write 'fan-fiction'. Naruto is also an anime! I use the term 'subcategory' extremely loosely!

Comment: I just realized that my problem was that I am trying to find which Sub-Categories apply to which category based on their appearance in a post with that sub-category, so your answer doesn't actually answer my question!